# Create a URL-friendly string

Tags: groovy

I have a string that I want to make url friendly. The string might look like this: `A string with $trange characters!".` and then I want to escape all the bad url-characters and end up with `a-string-with-trange-characters`

What is the best way to accomplish this in Groovy?

Comment: Just a word of caution: if you ever have two otherwise distinct partially-"strange" strings, your method will sometimes resolve them to **identical** URL-friendly equivalents. Hopefully when you include these in an actual URL you will also include a unique numeric identifier. Moreover, beware of the case when the given string is entirely "strange", e.g. `ノー` or `$$$!`, for in that case your result will be empty and you have to be careful how you integrate it in the URL to avoid URLs of the form `http://host/some/path//id`, where the result should have been in between `path` and `id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does this work?

```
string.replaceAll( /[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/, '' ).tr( ' ', '-' )
```

Answer (score 5):

In many cases, you may wish to not completely strip non-alphanumeric characters, but to decompose them first:

```
import java.text.Normalizer

println Normalizer.normalize("String with \$strang\u00E9 chars", Normalizer.Form.NFD)
    .replaceAll(/[^A-z0-9 ]/, "")
    .replaceAll(/ +/, "-")
```

In the above, `\u00E9` is 'é'. Decomposition turns this into the character 'e' and the combining mark '´'. Therefore when you apply the transformations the result is 'strange-' rather than 'strang-'.

Note that this isn't the whole story in getting ASCII-friendly versions of given strings... It won't convert '[ß](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00df/index.htm)' to 'ss' for example. I'm not aware of the best way to do that in Java/Groovy (using toUpperCase().toLowerCase() on the initial string seems a bit 'hacky').